# get the field names straight from the db table

Tags: php

I’m building a database driven website using WAMP

I have database with table called userinfo with the following field names 
DateTime  DomainName  ComputerName  UserName  NetworkSettings.

And I have a PHP script with a HTML table

```
echo "<div id='tableheading'>\n";
echo "<table class='data' border='1'align='center'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";

echo "<th> DateTime </th>
echo "<th> DomainName </th>
echo "<th> ComputerName </th>
echo "<th> UserName </th>
echo "<th> NetworkSettings </th>
```

How do I get the field names straight from the database?

Comment: @ajreal "M" in WAMP stands for Mysql, silly :)

Comment: But, don't give clues for any outsider to guess your database/table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using WAMP, I assume you're talking about MySQL. Have a look at [mysqli_result::fetch_fields()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php).

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against that

1. It's better to give field names plain lowercase names
2. HTML table headers often mismatch db table field names
3. Typing field names by hand is not as hard as you imagine

Comment: +1 but it can be useful if you have to generate tables on the fly from tables whose structure you don't know yet though

Comment: Absolutely but when you have to process *any* database, this really is necessary.